# Async operation showing wrong file

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task

I am trying to add an item to an ObservableCollection while in an aysnc operation. If I run the application, the collection does not have the correct file. If I step through it, I see the correct file does get added, which obviously shows a timing issue. Trouble is I cannot figure out how to fix it. Besides this, everything else works as I expect.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it so the correct filename is written to the ObservableCollection?

```
private void ChangeFile(INotificationComplete notification)
{
FileInfo currentFileInfo = null;

var destinationImageFilename = string.Empty;

var imageDestinationFolder = Path.Combine(messageBrokerInstance.GetProgramPath("LevelThreeFilesWebLocation", this.SelectedPlatform), "images");

var fileDestinationFolder = Path.Combine(messageBrokerInstance.GetProgramPath("LevelThreeFilesWebLocation", this.SelectedPlatform));

try
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)delegate
    {
        string[] files = null;

        if (directoryInfo.Exists)
        {
            files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryInfo.FullName, @"*.htm", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        }

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            currentFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

            **// bunch of code

            // I've found what I want and now am ready to write the file  
            // and add the filename to the collection the user sees.**


            if (writeFile)
            {
                var fileDestination = Path.Combine(fileDestinationFolder, currentFileInfo.Name);

                File.WriteAllLines(webFileDestination, fileArray);

                **// Correct file was written but the wrong filename
                // is added to the collection.**
                // If I step through this, the correct filename is added.
                UIDispatcher.Current.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    this.ChangedFiles.Add(currentFileInfo.Name);   // ChangedFiles is an ObservableCollection<string>
                });
            }
        }

        WaitAnimationNotification offNotification = new WaitAnimationNotification()
        {
            IsWaitAnimationOn = false,
            WaitAnimationMessage = "Please wait while the operation completes..."
        };

        WaitAnimationNotification waitNotification = notification as WaitAnimationNotification;

        if (waitNotification.IsWaitAnimationOn)
        {
            this.SendMessage("ToggleWaitAnimation", new NotificationEventArgs<WaitAnimationNotification, INotificationComplete>("ToggleWaitAnimation", offNotification));
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what `UIDispatcher.Current` is, but the correct Dispatcher to use is `Application.Current.Dispatcher` It's easy to spin up a separate dispatcher on a background thread unintentionally - which will give you the behavior you see. `Application.Current.Dispatcher` is going to be the correct dispatcher for the main application message pump

Comment: UIDispatcher.Current is a SimpleMVVM wrapper around Application.Current.Dispatcher